# Filling the reference information and Means of support section in Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, refunds, business-travel

I encountered the following while filling in the reference information. I will be staying at a hotel in Germany for 7 days. During my stay, I will be participating a three-day workshop at a research institute in Germany to which I am invited so it looks like I should write the name of the research institute in the "**Name of the organisation, company or hotel**" slot.

1. Not sure what to write in the "**Name of the register of the
   organization**", "**Location of register**", and "**Register number**" slots?
   or should they be left vacant in that case?
2. If the institute is going to fund my travel and accommodation during my stay where I am going to pay in advance with my credit card and send them my receipts and they will reimburse me later then, I should be choosing "**credit cards + assumption of all expenses during the stay**" option in the "**Means of Support**" section?

Comment: I am not an expert in this area but if the institute is going to refund you then the fact that you are going to have to pay first does not alter the fact that they are responsible for your travel costs.

Comment: I don't think this is part of the harmonised Schengen visa application form. Could you edit your question to include an image of the the form you are filling out? The harmonised application form has separate fields for "_Surname and first name of the inviting person(s) in the Member State(s). If not applicable, name of hotel(s) or temporary accommodation(s) in the Member State(s)_" (in your case, your hotel) and "_Name and address of inviting company/organisation_" (in your case, the research institute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question: They're asking about the legal registration of the institution you're visiting. This information should be specified in the "Impressum" ("Imprint" or legal information) on their website.

For example, let's assume the research institution you're visiting was a Fraunhofer institute. In that case, you'd check their "Impressum" where you'll find the requested information. In this example, the name of the register would be "Vereinsregister" (register of associations), the location would be Munich and the register number would be VR4461.

Happy to help you to find this information for your inviting institution if you'd like to share those details.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is Max Planck Institute for Mathematics in the sciences, Leipzig, Germany

Comment: That will be the "Vereinsregister" in Berlin-Charlottenburg, register number VR13378B. Similar to the Fraunhofer example, Max Planck institutes usually belong to a single Max Planck legal entity, which happens to be registered in Berlin. Source: The "impressum" for your institute at mis.mpg.de/imprint/index.html
(Deleted an earlier comment as I misread the impressum.)